# WP_Query arguments setting for ID

Tags: wordpress

I would like to do the WP_Query with the arguments setting as below, plus "WHERE ID > $post_id" (specific post id).
Pls advise how to add this WHERE clause into the $arg setting?
Thanks a lot.

```
$args = array (
            'cat'              => $category_id,
            'nopaging'               => false,
            'posts_per_page'         => '5',
            'order'                  => 'DESC',
            'orderby'                => 'ID'
            );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query "all post with an ID superior to X", I think you need to do like this :

```
$post_ids = range(25, 50); //we need an array of post IDs

$args = [
'posts_per_page' => 25, // if you want to limit/paginate the query
'post__in' => $post_ids
];

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

This will query all post from IDs 25 to 50 included. Pagination may be useful if you have a very large range of IDs to query. [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827671/how-to-get-posts-greater-than-x-id-using-get-posts).

Note that this will not generate a `WHERE` SQL clause, but a `WHERE IN`. To get a real `MySQL WHERE`, I think you'll to go with custom SQL query, as `WP_Query` doesn't provide a lot of operators on the post IDs.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mtxz & Ash0ur, I will check it out.

Comment: Ok! Please report here when your tests are done to confirm that it works for you.

Comment: set $post_ids in a range and use 'post__in' to filter, it's working!! I do the query for a category, its post_id is not consecutive, so i set the range of ($post_id-100, $post_id). Thanks a lot for the great help, Mtxz.

Comment: Cool! Mark the issue as resolved by accepting an answer. This way other users will quickly see how you managed to fix this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

oops, didn't see the > sign
you can use post__in with posts ids as @Mtxz answered above

```
'post__in' => array( )
```

Comment: OP wrote `WHERE ID > $post_id` so I think that he doesn't want to retrieve only 1 post, but all post with that have an ID superior to a given number.

Comment: Didn't say It, Thanks @Mtxz