# How to get posts with ID less than some number WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-tags

I want to get posts in WordPress with meta query where I check ID of user and some meta

```
$meta_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => 'assigne',
            'value' => get_current_user_id(),
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'team_id',
            'value' => $team,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'ID',
        'value' => 157,
        'compare' => '<',
    ),
);

$tasks = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby'     => 'ID',
    'order'       => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => $meta_query,
    'post_type'   => 'task',
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'suppress_filters' => true, 
) );
print_r($tasks);
```

But my `$meta_query` doesn't work. When I print posts, I see empty array. Where are a mistake in the code? **How to compare ID in meta query?**

For example, I have posts which ID is 155, 156 and 157. And I want to get posts with ID 155 and 156.

Comment: The post ID is not a _meta_ value - it is part of the `posts` table itself, not outsourced into the `postmeta` table.

Comment: @CBroe but how to get posts with smaller ID? It is possible? Which query I need?

Comment: I am not sure if WP has a default way of doing that. There are parameters to select by specific post ID or from a list of post IDs (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-page-parameters) - but there is no comparison operator at this point, so that you could do a greater-than / lesser-than. (And with good reason, because IDs should rather not be used for _anything_ else, other than uniquely identifying a record.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36258386/1427878 - this suggest to use `post__in`, and creates an array of all the "possible" IDs below the target one for that; but I don't know how performant that will be if you get into the hundreds or more ...